# How to get maximum value from DB using sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

Trying to get specific maximum value from DB using sequelize. I have this code, which works without an include part, but I need to filter data acccording to Address. I am trying it this way:

```
 Carrier.max('code', {
         where: {
             equipmentTypeID: id,
             id: {
                 $not: carrierID
             }
          },
         include: [{
             model: Address,
             as: 'address',
             where: {
                 district: city.name
             },
         }]
     })
```

Carrier model:

```
 Carrier.belongsTo(MODEL('database/address').instance, {
         foreignKey: 'addressID',
         onDelete: 'SET NULL'
     });
```

but I get this error:

```
 Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: column "address.id" must 
 appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I cant figure out how to add GROUP BY clause with address.id.

**EDITED**

this is my actual solution:

```
 Carrier.max('code', {
         where: {
             equipmentTypeID: id,
             id: {
                 $not: carrierID
             }
          },
         include: [{
             model: Address,
             as: 'address',
             where: {
                 district: city.name
             },
         }],
         group: 'address.id'  
     })
```

but it not return correct row (for example it returns 'yyyy' but good answer is 'zzzz').

Column 'carrier.code' is type of text, but it also doesn't work with 'carrier.id'. Is there a way to make Carrier.findAll() with this specific filter and then make max() function on results? Or there is some other way to get max column value from specific rows?

Comment: How do you have the association between Carrier and Address?

Comment: Carrier belongs to Address, I also edited a question...

Comment: Then yo should add on the belongsTo the clause "as : 'address'", because that is how you're calling it on the include. Or just remove the "as" from the include. Should work like that.

Comment: I tried both but still the same result